# iphone webview doubts

Tags: ios-simulator

I was wondering, how can I use 1 UIWebView controller to open multiple URLs.
I have 5 buttons, and each button should open different website, so I want to know how to use one XIB with UIWebView to open different URL everytime and not use 5 UIWebView and 5 XIBs.

Comment: I see that you haven't accepted any answers. If you found my answer to be helpful, you should accept it and if you didn't you should leave a comment to let me know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simple. Do the following:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"]]];
```

**EDIT:** If you need to load multiple images, you need to write HTML to handle that. Once you've figured out how to write the HTML you use the following method:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

Comment: i write this code but i cant acesses multiple url in webviews..multiple url contains images from server..i have to load both the images from the server to my webview at a time,,

Comment: this is not i am looking for,,becz i need to load multiple images from diffrent url ,to load in a single webview in my application

Comment: @nipin Updated my answer. It includes what you need, except you need to write the HTML yourself. If you don't know how to do that, there are plenty of good tutorials for learning HTML on the Internet. I'm sure Google can help you find one.

Comment: [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];

Comment: if [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:resultstring]]]; result string has 3 images ,,how can i load resulsting to  webview?

Comment: [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL]; where did i put this code ???

Answer (score 0):

Write an HTML code. Place 5 image tag. Fill each imgsrc with each url and load the html string. Better get the support of a web developer to write the html code.